# Allowing Pods to communicate with other pods via Network Policies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I do have a situation where, I do have 3 pods in the same namespace. Lets call them `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`.

Meanwhile NetworkPolicies are set in each of 2 of these to accept and forward traffic, let's say the `netpol` for `aaa` is `npa` and for `bbb` is `npb`

My question is how can I allow `ccc` to allow traffic to ingress only from `aaa` and `bbb` by only configuring the pod and existing network policies

Answer (score 5):

You can label the pods and add the network policy as shown below, it should allow traffic from aaa/bbb to ccc pod only

label existing pod:

```
kubectl label pod aaa "ns=aaa"
kubectl label pod bbb "ns=aaa"
```

Network Policy: The below network policy will apply on pod ccc(app: ccc) and will only allow traffic from pods aaa and bbb this is what is required

note: assumed ccc is labelled as app: ccc

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ccc
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns: aaa
```